# click outside div left will be 0px

Tags: jquery, css

I used this code to show a `div` left from right. Now I want the `div` left position to be 0 with animation when `clicked` outside the `div`.

Live url:- http://emoncmt2.byethost15.com/App/bayar.html

```
$('.top-tittle .menu-icon').click(function () {

  var targetValue;

  if ($('.main-menu').css('left') == "0px") {
    targetValue = '-78%';
  } else {
    targetValue = '0px';
  }

  $(".main-menu").animate({
    left: targetValue
  }, 400);


});
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: http://emoncmt2.byethost15.com/App/bayar.html check this url. I want to hide the main-menu div when click outside this div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.top-title .menu-icon').click(function() {
  var targetValue;

  if ($('.main-menu').css('left') == "0px") {
    targetValue = '-78%';
  } else {
    targetValue = '0px';
  }

  $(".main-menu").animate({
    left: targetValue
  }, 400);
});

$(document).on('click', function(e){
  var $target = $(e.target);
  
  //if the element is the menu icon, or is a child of the menu, ignore the click
  if (!$target.is('.menu-icon') && $target.closest('.main-menu').length < 1) {
    //doesn't belong to the icon or the menu, close the menu
    $('.main-menu').stop().animate({
      left: '-78%'
    }, 400);
  }
});
```

```css
.top-title {
  background-color: red;
}

.menu-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 36px;
  min-height: 36px;
  background-color: black;
}

.main-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top:36px;
  left: -78%;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 78%;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-title">
  <div class="menu-icon"></div>
</div>

<div class="main-menu"><p>Weeee</p></div>
```

Comment: Actually, Your one is Best.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding something like this:

```
$('body').click(function(ev) {
    var $target = $(ev.target);
    var clicked_icon = ($target.hasClass('menu-icon') || $target.closest('.menu-icon').length > 0);
    var clicked_menu = ($target.hasClass('main-menu') || $target.closest('.main-menu').lenght > 0);

    if (!clicked_icon && !clicked_menu) {
        $(".main-menu").animate({
            left: '-78%'
         }, 400);
    }
});
```

This is saying: `when the user clicks on the page and does NOT click on .main-menu, move the menu to the left.`

Comment: Yep @Taplar, you are right. Just added it to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Without using `.stop()` you're in the risk of buildup animations. I.E: click 100 times on body, than try to open the menu. In short - don't run animations if there's no need to.

Comment: @rideron89 Check this link please http://emoncmt2.byethost15.com/App/bayar.html  when click the menu icon then it show and click menu icon again then it will be hide. I want when click outside main-menu menu div it hide also.

Comment: @AhsanHabibEmon you should really open your console and fix those errors. Than try to implement the suggested and come back if you have any further comments.

Comment: @AhsanHabibEmon I just updated it to work with your menu icon. Though I'd recommend toggling a class, rahter than changing the CSS here.

Comment: I try below code and it works fine. But menu shows top left to right. not full left to right.    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.top-tittle .menu-icon').click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
         $(".main-menu").toggle( "slide");
    });
    $(".main-menu").on("click", function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});

$(document).on("click", function () {
    $(".main-menu").hide(500);
});